# How can I create multiple threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, xlsx

I am working on python 3 and my class is as below.

```
class MyClass():
     def values(self):
        ***values***

     i =0
     def check_values(self):
         for i in ValueList[i:i+1]:
              self.server_connect()
              new_value = self.update.values(i)

      def run(self):
          self.check_values()

if __name__ == "__main__"
     format1 = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
     logging.basicConfig(format=format1, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

     for i in range(4):
          thread = threading.Thread(target=MyClass().run())
          threads.append(thread)
          i += 1
          print("the %s thread is running", thread)
          thread.start()
```

There are no threads getting created but code works.
I am not able to catch what I am doing wrong here.

***EDIT***

First, I would like to thank you for response and time given for the answer. 
I have to update code and inherit other class as per new update from team as below.

```
class MyClass(MainServer):
```

Now, the server has it's own run function as below.

```
class MainServer(object):
   ***constructor***
   ***other functions ***
     def run(self):
         self.add_arguments()
         self.parse_arguments()
         self.check_values()
```

Now, without run(), my code is not properly running. 
while including run() as below.

```
*** main ***
update_perform = MyClass()
for i range(4):
     thread = threading.Thread(target=Myclass().run()) <-- code starts from here 
     threads.append(thread)
     i += 1
     print("the %s thread is running", thread)
     thread.start()    <-- not reaching till here
```

As per my knowledge I will require thread.start() to start threading. So I have tried below option

```
class MyClass(MainServer):
     ***code as above***
   def check_values(self):
        self.server_authenticate()
        update_value = self.update.values()

    def run(self):
         self.server_connect()
         i = 0
         threads = list()
         for i in ValueList[i:i+1]:
             print("Updating the value = ", i)
             thread = threading.Thread(target=check_values(), args=[i])
             thread.start()
             i += 1
             print("Currently running thread", thread)
             threads.append(thread)
         for thread in threads:
              thread.join()
```

Here thread is executing from start and in print I can see as below

```
for threading :- 
Currently running threads = <Thread(Thread-8, stopped 14852)>
```

But for the value I can see only one is in process as below

```
for value :- 
Updating the value = 10  <- first value
```

So, now threads may be getting created but the values are not getting executed in parallel.

Which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA :- I am implementing your solution only and update the result to you.

Answer (score 1):

modify the run function like this

```py
def run(self):
   self.check_values()
```

Comment: Hi @jai, Thank you for response. Actually I have multi threaded application. Here I need to create thread limiting to 4 numbers.

Comment: @zerocool3: This answer seems to address the obvious issue with the code you show up above, that you never *call* `check_values` from `run` (you just reference it). Within `check_values` you're also misusing the variable `i` somehow, but I have no idea what you actually want to be doing with it.

Comment: @Blckknght :- I understand it will never call ```run``` , I have updated that as well.

Comment: @Jai : thank you for response. I have made one print and I seeing print as below.```Currently running threads = <Thread(Thread-8, stopped 14852)>``` But at a time I see only one price getting checked not 4 or 5( which is I have to limit).